# Overlap error (PCB design) using Eagle

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

[image: Design showing overlap error]

The picture shows an overlap error. I am unable to resolve this error and need to know if any rules are broken?

The component is a flip-flop resistor (0805-THM, AdaFruit).
Wherever I used this resistor, it's throwing the same error.

Comment: A circuit diagram of the relevant section might help.  Knowing what layout tool you are using certainly would.

Comment: @WarrenHill Eagle

Comment: You are a new user so I will forgive you but please try and put relevant details in the question and not comments.  I've edited your question for you this time.

Comment: @WarrenHill Thank you for rectifying me and apologies for the mistake.

Comment: @WarrenHill Surprisingly, even when this resistor is completely unconnected, error persists. Issue might be with the library? Shall I use different one.

Comment: Worth a try.  Remove the resistor entirely. Does the problem go away? Next try a different resistor.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the name of the top trace. It should be GND. Otherwise you'll get an overlap error.

Answer (score 0):

Ripup the last bit of trace from both signals, and reconnect.  Will also show you if have two different signals going into the same pin.

Ripup all Gnd signals and replace with top & bottom layer Polygons that you Name GND.  Select Rats nest and let the GNDs connect that way.  Routing GND traces all over the board is never a good idea.

Draw the Polygons just outside the dimension of the board. Add Vias and Name them GND to connect the top and bottom layers together.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Being a novice, I could not understand what 'replace with top & bottom layer Polygons that you Name GND'  means.                                                                            Also how to avoid routing GND everywhere as you mentioned.                           This AdaFruit library of resistor I'm using is inbuilt one (0805-THM, AdaFruit). 
Sorry to trouble you again.

Comment: And even when this resistor is connected to any other components, it shows overlap error. Any reasons sir?

Comment: Raj, The resistor pictured is a thruhole part, not an 0805 which is definitely a surface mount part.  Send me your file, I'll change it tonight and return, you'll be able to see what I changed for the Polygon and the Gnds. I'll see what is going on with the overlap.  Robert at crossroadsfencing dot com

Comment: I have mailed you, sir!